# Feasible to adapt JSX 'import' to use http?

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently brainstorming a http react component service (http://components.myCompany.com). It seems feasible, if the import directive could make an http request to grab a component. Then a consumer, likely compiling their JSX as a build step on the server side, could reference components coming from this service. E.g.

```
/**
 * @jsx React.DOM
 */

module React from 'react';
import Timer from 'http://components.myCompany.com/Timer';
```

I've spent some time rooting into the react-tools nodejs module. Enough to realize that I can't quickly deduce exactly how the import statement transforms into actual component JavaScript inlined to the eventual JS file. So, asking for others who know the transformation process well enough to address the feasibility of this.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, the JSX compiler doesn't do anything with ES6 import syntax. Did you see something that indicated it does?

Comment: Hm. My ignorance shows perhaps.. If this jsx is transformed via the react-tools transform, is it just the ES6 directive that inlines the 'imported' code?

Comment: react-tools doesn't touch ES6 import lines at all. If you're getting them in its output it means that you had them in your input as well.

Comment: I didn't realize the react code I was looking at was run through a gulp task which inlines code from import statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform all your components in modules and publish them in GitHub (or in a HTTP server), and set them as dependency using URLs

On your package.json, you can set:

```
"dependencies": {
   "Timer": "http://components.myCompany.com/Timer.tar.gz"
}
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies

Later, you can import it in React:

`import Timer from 'Timer';`